# Storing booleans in Active Record Store

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a standard rails form to update an ActiveRecord::Store

```
  store :settings, accessors: %i[is_public]
```

My form looks like this:

```
<%= form.select(:is_public, options_for_select([['True', true], ['False', false]])) %>
```

When I look at the saved hash these have been converted to strings, is there a way to preserve the boolean type here?

Comment: Is there a reason why this isn't a true attribute (i.e. stored in the table)? If so you can overwrite the accessor [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html)

Comment: I'm just trying to store all my user settings in one columns rather than have a lot of columns for the 30+ settings params, is there a better way?

Comment: No that is fine and now more understandable but in that case I would recommend overwriting the accessor as shown in the docs.

Comment: I created a custom module to add methods to overwrite the accessor, as @engineersmnky suggests (see below).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to write a CustomStoreAccessor module to overwrite the accessor for  these attributes:

```
module CustomStoreAccessor
  def boolean_store_accessor(attr_name)
    define_method "#{attr_name}=" do |value|
      super(value=='true')
    end

    define_method attr_name do
       super()=='true'
    end
  end

  def integer_store_accessor(attr_name)
    define_method "#{attr_name}=" do |value|
      super(value.to_i)
    end

    define_method attr_name do
      super().to_i
    end
  end
end
```

This then allows me to add these methods to my model:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  extend CustomStoreAccessor
  store :settings_object, accessors: %i[is_public max_sessions]
  boolean_store_accessor :is_public
  integer_store_accessor :max_sessions
```

Comment: since your methods are logically named I would recommend changing `boolean_store_accessor` to `super(value == 'true')` and `super() == 'true'` respectively because if this is truely intended to be a boolean then I would expect a boolean at all times. Also the `to_sym` in `"#{attr_name}=".to_sym` is not needed a `String` is perfectly acceptable

Comment: This really just begs the question "But why?". Native JSON types have been a thing for many years now and your driver will convert booleans and numbers to and from JSON columns without any of this.